# How to make a method suitable for classes implementing an interface?

Tags: java, generics

How can I make the following method suitable for any class implementing the `String getValue()` interface? Is this possible with Generics?

```
private static void findUniqueEntriesInList(List<ColValueObject> list1, 
                                            List<ColValueObject> list2, 
                                            List<ColValueObject> result) {
    for (ColValueObject l1 : list1) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (ColValueObject l2 : list2) {
        if (l1.getValue().equals(l2.getValue())) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) {
        result.add(l1);
      }
    }
  }
```

with:

```
class ColValueObject implements GetValueToStringObject {
  private String base;
  private String value;
  // boilerplate omitted
}
```

I could create this interface and method:

```
public interface GetValueToStringObject {
  String getValue();
}
```

and:

```
private static void findUniqueEntriesInListUsingGenerics(List<GetValueToStringObject> list1,
                                                           List<GetValueToStringObject> list2,
                                                           List<GetValueToStringObject> result) {
    for (GetValueToStringObject l1 : list1) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (GetValueToStringObject l2 : list2) {
        if (l1.getValue().equals(l2.getValue())) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) {
        result.add(l1);
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that I cannot directly call the method like this:

```
findUniqueEntriesInListUsingGenerics(list1, list2, result);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but obviously, `List<GetValueToStringObject>` is not a `List<ColValueObject>` nor vice versa, and given there is no implements (or extends) relationship between `GetValueToStringObject` and `ColValueObject`, as it stands your method cannot work.

Making some reasonable assumption, I think you'll need `ColValueObject` to implement `GetValueToStringObject`. You can then use generics with `<T extends GetValueToStringObject>` to do what you want:

```java
class ColValueObject implements GetValueToStringObject {
  private String base;
  private String value;

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
  // boilerplate omitted
}
```

Then implement your method as:

```java
private static <T extends GetValueToStringObject> void findUniqueEntriesInListUsingGenerics(
    List<T> list1, List<T> list2, List<T> result) {
  for (T l1 : list1) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (T l2 : list2) {
      if (l1.getValue().equals(l2.getValue())) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      result.add(l1);
    }
  }
}
```

With this, all lists must have the same generic type, see the end of the answer for a more flexible solution.

As an aside, I think the `result` parameter doesn't belong in your method, and that it should return a `List<T>` created in the method. For example:

```java
private static <T extends GetValueToStringObject> List<T> findUniqueEntriesInListUsingGenerics(
    List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
  List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
  // ... code above
  return result;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to allow `list1`, `list2` and `result` to have different types, you can use:

```java
private static <T extends GetValueToStringObject> void findUniqueEntriesInListUsingGenerics(
        List<T> list1, 
        List<? extends GetValueToStringObject> list2, 
        List<? super T> result) {
    for (T l1 : list1) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (GetValueToStringObject l2 : list2) {
            if (l1.getValue().equals(l2.getValue())) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            result.add(l1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `list1` is defined as the actual type, `list2` can be any list of types extending (implementing) `GetValueToStringObject`, and `result` can be a list of any superclass/superinterface of `T`.

For example, if `list1` is `List<ColValueObject>`, then `result` can be `List<ColValueObject>`, `List<GetValueToStringObject>` or `List<Object>`, and `list2` can be `List<GetValueToStringObject>`, `List<ColValueObject>`, or `List<SomeOtherTypeImplementingGetValueToStringObject>`.

Another option is below, but this restricts the type of `result` to only `List<GetValueToStringObject` and `List<Object>`, which I think is less useful than the previous solution:

```java
private static  void findUniqueEntriesInListUsingGenerics(
        List<? extends GetValueToStringObject> list1, 
        List<? extends GetValueToStringObject> list2, 
        List<? super GetValueToStringObject> result) {
    for (GetValueToStringObject l1 : list1) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (GetValueToStringObject l2 : list2) {
            if (l1.getValue().equals(l2.getValue())) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            result.add(l1);
        }
    }
}
```